# Need help understanding newtons method for spheres

Tags: geometry, spheres

Currently I am trying to understand how Newtons method works by finding a point that lies on the surface of a sphere.

Currently, my understanding is as follows:

```
        Sphere equation: (x - a)2 + (y - b)2 + (z - c)2 = r2
            where a, b, c = center of sphere
            where x, y, z = sample location
            where r2 = radius squared
```

Lets say we have a sphere located at (5, 6, 1) and radius 2.

The equation becomes:

> (x - 5)2 + (y - 6)2 + (z - 1)2 = 4.

So if we want to know if a point (x, y, z) lies on a sphere, we can start with an initial sampling position:

> (s1) = (8, 9, 4)

We now want to find the next position, which we can do with the following equation:

```
        s2 = s1 - (f(s1) / f`(s1))
            where   (s2) = second sample location (target)
                    f(s1) = first sample location's equation
                    f`(s1) = derivative of the sample
```

So,

```
f(s1) = (8 - 5)2 + (9 - 6)2 + (4 - 1)2 = 13.24
```

Now, we need to find the derivative of a sphere, which i think is:

> 4 * pi * (r * r)

which is

> 4 * pi * (2 * 2) = 50.26548

So, pluggin everything in, our equation becomes:

```
s2 = s1 - (13.24 / 50.26548)
```

which makes the second sample position be:

```
(7.462852, 8.462852, 3.462852)
```

I feel like my understanding of this is wrong, since even after 100 iterations, this does not seem to converge to a point where the dot(sample - center) == radius * radius.

Could someone try to explain this to me please?

Comment: If you want to know if a point lies on the sphere just substitute its $x, y$ and $z$ in the equation of the sphere, and see if it satisfies the equation.  This is not where Newton's method is used.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'd like to extend this in the future to a least squares solution for multiple spheres

Comment: I think you could 1) begin by working on circles in a plane instead of spheres in 3D 2) Explain the extension you intend to consider to multiple spheres (explain it with circles), because the objective with a single circle is indeed strange : we don't understand the interest of Newton's method here.

Comment: I think the function needs to include the radius also $$f(s) = (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 - r^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the derivative with area, in higher dimension it's a bit more complicated than what you think, the derivative of the sphere formula is a vector
$(2(x-5),2(y-6),2(z-1))$, to use Newton's method you need to compute the inverse of the matrix
$Df(s1) = \begin{pmatrix} 2(x-5) & 2(y-6) & 2(z-1) \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 &\end{pmatrix} $
Then apply it to your vector:
$$ (s_2,0,0) = (s_1,0,0)-[Df(s_1)]^{-1}(f(s_1),0,0)$$

I'll let more experienced applied mathematicians answer how you get your inverse matrix, since I have 0 experience with that.

Of course, the way to actually get a point on the sphere can be obtained in a simpler manner by considering the retraction:
$$ P = (8,9,4)\ \  r=2 \ \  s_1\in \mathbb{R}^3\ \ \ s_2=r\frac{s_1-P}{\|s_1-P\|} + p \in S_r^2(P)$$

Where
$$ \| (x,y,z) \| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve the problem for 2 sphere intersections, not for multiple unfortunately

Comment: Could you meaby try to explain a little bit more about the matrix? I just fill it with all the derivatives, compute the inverse, and then do s1 - (error / derivMatrix)?